# groovy removeAll closure not removing elements in list

Tags: groovy

I'm not sure how removeAll in groovy works, but I expected this to return [40289454470ea94601470ea977d00018]

```
def list = ['40289454470ea94601470ea977b20014', '40289454470ea94601470ea977d00018']
def list2 = ['40289454470ea94601470ea977b20014']

list.removeAll {
   list2
}

println list
```

but instead it returns []

please enlighten :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

removeAll with a Closure removes every element that the closure returns true for

list2 coerces to true under groovy truth as it isn't empty so your code removes everything

Try

```
list1 -= list2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `removeAll` closure, you should simply use the `removeAll` method.

```
list.removeAll {
   list2
}
```

The way with closure to go :

```
list.removeAll {
   list2.contains(it)
}
```

If `list2` contains this element, then it's removed from `list`

Comment: i can't seem to get this to work. The subtraction works but not removeAll.    def a1 = ['hello','world']
  def a2 = ['hello','world']
  def list2 = ['world']
  a2.removeAll {
   list2.contains(it)
  }
  a1 -= list2
  echo a1.join(",")
  echo a2.join(",")